# How to save each sheet as a separate workbook except sheet 1?

Tags: excel, vba

I have an excel workbook with 5 sheets but I only want to save sheet 2 to sheet - 5  but I don't want to save sheet 1. I want to exclude it from saving. How can I do it?

I have tried some codes but I am having difficulties.

```
Sub SaveShtsAsBook()

    Dim xcsvFile As String
    Dim datestring As String
    Dim Count As Integer


    datestring = DateValue(Now) & Time
    datestring = Replace(datestring, "/", "_")
    datestring = Replace(datestring, ":", "_")
    datestring = Replace(datestring, " ", "_")

'    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
'    Application.Visible = False

    Application.EnableEvents = True
   ' Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  '  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    For Count = 1 To 3000
    DoEvents
    Next Count


    'For Each Sheet In Worksheets
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' Safer way to qualify the worksheets with the workbook where this code lies

       Select Case Sheet.Name
        Case "Sheet1"
        ' do nothing

        Case Else
           xcsvFile = "E:\" & xWs.Name & "_" & datestring & ".csv"
       ' xcsvFile = "E:\" & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv" 'compare mine to yours to see issues

        xWs.Copy

        Dim newSheet As Workbook 'setting copied sheet to workbook variable for easier coding
        Set newSheet = ActiveSheet.Parent 'parent of worksheet is workbook

        newSheet.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
        newSheet.Close False
       End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What is the problem with the code you are currently using?

Comment: I am getting the run-time error : '424'

Comment: So basically I want to run the code which saves each excel sheets seperately except sheet 1.

Answer (score 3):

The problem is you were referring to `xWs` variable which doesn't exist on your code. If you change it with `Sheet`, it works perfectly as I tested on my Excel:

```
Sub SaveShtsAsBook()
    Dim xcsvFile As String
    Dim datestring As String
    Dim Count As Integer

    datestring = DateValue(Now) & Time
    datestring = Replace(datestring, "/", "_")
    datestring = Replace(datestring, ":", "_")
    datestring = Replace(datestring, " ", "_")

'    Application.WindowState = xlMinimized
'    Application.Visible = False

    Application.EnableEvents = True
   ' Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
  '  Application.Wait (Now + TimeValue("0:00:10"))

    For Count = 1 To 3000
        DoEvents
    Next Count


    'For Each Sheet In Worksheets
    For Each Sheet In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets ' Safer way to qualify the worksheets with the workbook where this code lies

        Select Case Sheet.Name
            Case "Sheet1"
            ' do nothing

            Case Else
            xcsvFile = "E:\" & Sheet.Name & "_" & datestring & ".csv"
            ' xcsvFile = "E:\" & "\" & xWs.Name & ".csv" 'compare mine to yours to see issues

            Sheet.Copy

            Dim newSheet As Workbook 'setting copied sheet to workbook variable for easier coding
            Set newSheet = ActiveSheet.Parent 'parent of worksheet is workbook

            newSheet.SaveAs Filename:=xcsvFile, FileFormat:=xlCSV, CreateBackup:=False
            newSheet.Close False
        End Select
    Next
End Sub
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: You're welcome. :) Please accept my answer so others can benefit from it.

Comment: How I can do that ?

Comment: To mark an answer as accepted, click on the check mark beside the answer to toggle it from greyed out to filled in. More info here: https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers